# vlookup and potential revenue formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

How do i Create a VLOOKUP formula to display Potential Revenue in cell, Using data from a different sheet, according to the Bid Amount in cell of first sheet.How do i create the formula to get the answer based on a dropdown value

I tried so many formulas after searching on google but i think there were errors in the formula and i did not get an exact formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG1eI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrvo4.png)

Please i need hyelp, i've been stucked here for too long

Comment: Once you have defined the table_array as referring to a particular sheet then it will work, gets tricky if you try to go between workbooks though... If you want, define the reference to the table_array as a name then it becomes easier to type etc So from the answer you have been given: "vlookup(B3,Pot_Rev,4,) where "Pot_Rev" is named as worksheet 2!G:J

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this in `Cell_C3`:*

```js
=vlookup(B3,'Worksheet 2'!G:J,4,)
```

Comment: Oh my God! I am so grateful it worked, Thank you so much

Comment: Please can you break down and explain to me, and why did you use 4. What column does it represent please, i have been using 2. I am new and i would really appreciate if you can explain so i won'[t get this kind of problem again.

Comment: Column_J is 4 columns right to Column_G; If you wish to avoid this column counting mechanism, go with xlookup: `=xlookup(B3,'Worksheet 2'!G:G,'Worksheet 2'!J:J,)`

Comment: Please check the first image, what formula do i use to solve question 3.. it is similar to question 2 that you solved for me

Comment: Yes question 3 uses the exact logic as question 2, for which the answer is provided and also explained. I'd suggest to use the logic and work it out since clearly looks like its some kind of test/homework??!

Comment: I've tried but i am getting error

Comment: Share the formula(s) you tried both of vlookup and xlookup...

Comment: The formula i used =vlookup(B3,'Worksheet 2'!G:H,1,)

Comment: Count all the columns in the provided range of `G:H`; that would be *2* as the index value (*& not 1*)

Comment: i got it using the xlookup, wow =vlookup(B5,'Worksheet 2'!G:H,1,)

Comment: You are a great teacher, thank you so much.. i understand this now